# Showing a message till php script is completed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my page for uploading an excel file and import the data in it to a mysql table. Since the query takes a bit time to complete, I want to show a GIF file showing "loading" till the entire records are inserted, and afterwards change the image to completed. Any work around please.

```
<?php

  require_once('Connections/met.php');
  $uploadedStatus = 0;

  if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
    if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {
      //if there was an error uploading the file
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
      }
      else {
        if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
          unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
        $storagename = "windrose_data.xlsx";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $storagename);
        $uploadedStatus = 1;
      }
    } else {
      echo "No file selected <br />";
    }
  }

  if($uploadedStatus==1){

    $db=mysql_select_db($database_met,$met);

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    // This is the file path to be uploaded.
    $inputFileName = 'windrose_data.xlsx'; 

    try {
      $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }


    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet

    for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
      $date = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
      $time = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
      $dir = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
      $spd = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);

      $insertTable= mysql_query("insert into wr_copy (date,time,dir,spd) values('$date', '$time',$dir,$spd)") or die(mysql_error());

      $msg = 'Record has been added. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';

    }
    echo "<div style='font: bold 18px arial,verdana;padding: 45px 0 0 500px;'>".$msg."</div>";

  }

?>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Import Excel file </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.j"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.noConflict();

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <table width="600" style="margin:115px auto; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid #eee; padding:10px;">

    <form action="<?php  echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <tr>
        <td width="50%" style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Select file</td>
        <td width="50%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px;"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Submit</td>
        <td width="50%" style=" padding:5px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>

</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a loading image gif or message while PHP is executing a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292952/how-to-display-a-loading-image-gif-or-message-while-php-is-executing-a-batch-fil)

Comment: This is not really possible with means of server side scripting alone. You will always need some client side scripting as well, so javascript. Two approaches exist: 1. periodic polling for success which monitors a server side process progress and 2. replace the html form based upload with an ajax alternative which offers progress feedback.

Comment: In my view, you can send an AJAX to that PHP page and show a loading GIF until the response is sent back to the client side

Comment: I know how to use jquery for normal post requests. Since this involves a file upload, I do not know how to handle. In the entire code, file upload does not take much time. But the query takes a bit more as it is another server. I am stumbling when it comes to upload file using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using ajaxupload library. The following script do the work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.3.5.js" ></script>

<script>    
$(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'upload-file.php',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(xls|xlsx)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // extension is not allowed 
                    status.text('Only xls, xlsx files are allowed');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Uploading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('');
                //Add uploaded file to list

                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html(response).addClass('success');

            }
        });

    });</script>
```

in upload_file.php folllowing lines arethere

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './uploads/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used jQuery but looks like not using jQuery ajax/post method to submit form which would be ideal way for this. A quick way for now can be by adding onsubmit event hadaller to the form and display loading image/message on form submit event.

```
<form action="<?php  echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="$('#loading').show(); return true;">
<div id='loading' style='display:none'> Loading message / Image Here...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use AJAX

Send your all processings to another page with AJAX.

In Java script, 
in your statechange (where you receive ajax response)

```
    function stateChanged1(){
            var zdivid="divid";

            if( xmlHttp.readyState!=3){
                    //SHOW YOUR GIF -- That's it
            }

            if ( xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete" )
            {
                    document.getElementById(zdivid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
    }
```

With Jquery

```
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url://your ajax url,
            data:'',
            contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
             beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                   //SHOW YOUR GIF -- That's it
                },

            success :function (data)
            {
                alert (data);
                //do whatever you want, after successful processing
            },
            error:function(request,status,error)
            {alert(error);}
    });
```